# java Authenticator class does not auth on POST

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, odata, dynamics-crm

I am creating a Spring Boot REST full service to send GET and POST request to CRM Dynamics.

CRM Dynamics using OData REST web service with NTLM Authentication.

In my case I'm using *Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator)* in this piece of code to authenticate (DAO constructor)

```
public CRMIntegrationDAO() {
    NtlmAuthenticator authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(CRMProps.getLogin(), CRMProps.getPassword());
    Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
}
```

But the strange thing is that this class is not authenticate my app on POST requests.
If I'm making GET request first it's works fine, and other GET and POST works too.
But if I want to make POST first I'm receiving **401: Unauthorized.**

In logs, I can see that on GET request my app calls CRM Dynamics from two to three times to be authorized.
But on POST it's creating only one request.

Is there any workaround for that class or any other solutions for NTLM authentication in Java/Spring Boot(except calling GET before POST).

P.S. CRM Dynamics admins says that there no API session settings on Dynamics side.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Code for POST request in DAO class

```
public ResponseEntity<String> processPOSTNewTask(String body) {
    log.debug(String.format("DAO received parameters: %s", body));

    String url = CRMProps.getUrl() + CRMProps.getTaskEntity();
    try {
        return processPOST(url, body);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return GlobalUtils.buildErrorResponseEntity(Utils.MODULE_NAME, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private ResponseEntity<String> processPOST(String url, String body) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity(body, setHeaders());

    log.debug("headers " + entity.getHeaders());

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you make the POST?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli sure I can. Please find in post.

Comment: and where do you do set the authenticator? Is it really set before the POST?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, the Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator) call is in DAO class constructor. I have edited code in the post

Comment: and the POST is also in the DAO?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yes but in the different method. GET request method have same structure.